# VS CODE Auto indentation configuration JavaScript/TypeScript conflict

Tags: visual-studio-code

In VS Code I have a configuration "format document" using ALT+SHIFT+F which is based on some configuration I cannot find where to alter.

The issue is that it overrides the configuration we have in our project so I won't get the same linting rules as the rest in the team.

The two problems I have is
- Formatting the document is having the wrong indentation (2 spaces should be 4)
- It automatically changes '' for imports to ""

I'm not sure if this is caused due to some extention I have, ie. prettier or beautify? Or some global linting rules? (should in any case be overriden by local settings)

Changing the configuration tabs/spaces in the bottom bar as explained on some guides does not affect the "format document" command. Why is that?

Comment: Do you have "editor:detectIndentation" set to false?  It defaults to true.  And one of the extensions is probably changing single to double quotes.  Or see   "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "auto", - changing that might fix your import quote styles.

Answer (score 1):

In the bottom info bar (with blue background on dark theme), on the right, there are several icons with information.
It turns out that there is more than information.
If you click on "Spaces: x", you can change the space indentation for the current file to whatever number you would like.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Hit the gear icon on the left-bottom side of your vscode window and open settings. In the `user settings` check if `"editor.formatOnSave"` is set to `true`. If yes, set it to `false` and then it won't format your code while saving.

Comment: Thanks but that's not the issue. I have that flag to false already. The issue is when I use the command described above (ALT+SHIFT+F) in order to "auto format the whole document". It uses the wrong indentation and I cannot change it.